# Custom hash based on data external to key

Tags: rust, hashmap

I have a read-only map:

```rust
struct Map {
    inner: HashMap<Key, Value>,
}
```

which I am trying to convert to the following layout:

```rust
struct Map {
    keys: Vec<Key>,
    inner: HashMap<usize /* index in [keys] */, Value>,
}
```

(I am doing this in order to optimize memory consumption - in real code `Key` stores some data in heap, and `keys` will be custom `Vec` which instead does one big heap allocation and store keys "inline")

Is it possible to write `get` method for such layout?

```rust
impl Map {
    pub fn get(&self, key: &Key) -> Option<&Value> {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to write such method as you asked? Yes. For example:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Map<K, V> {
    keys: Vec<K>,
    inner: HashMap<usize /* index in [keys] */, V>,
}

impl<K, V> Map<K, V> {
    pub fn get(&self, key: &K) -> Option<&V>
    where
        K: std::cmp::Eq
    {
       let index = self.keys.iter().position(|k| k == key);
       index.map(|i| self.inner.get(&i).unwrap())
    }
}
```

But should you use it? Probably not.

I didn't quite understand what you are trying to do, but putting keys in a `Vec` and storing values in a map with vec's indexes as keys is *really odd* and is always more inefficient and less ergonomic than using singe vec, or single map.

Notice that in `get` you must do:

1. linear search of key in `Vec`
2. calculate hash of given index
3. maintain invariant that each key in `0..keys.len()` is a valid key in the `HashMap`

which is (generally) more work than just storing `(K, V)` pair in `Vec` and doing linear search for the key, or hashing key and doing a lookup in the `HashMap` (like in your first example).

Moreover this leads to greater fragmentation (keys and values are likely on different pages in memory (since they are separately allocated) and in practice you can only easily remove keys from the end of the `Vec`, since removing keys from the middle would result in changing of indexes and the hash map would need to be recalculated.

Concluding, it is possible but you probably should not do it. Just keep using `HashMap<K, V>` or use `Vec<(K, V)>` if you want to perform linear search. And if you want to further optimize, measure first and be very certain that you know what you want to do.